# NSMutableArray shuffle issue

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, shuffle

I have solved the problem with including terminating method.

```
If(indexes==0){
endUp = YES;
}
```

Thanks for pointing me the right direction. It wasn't problem of the shuffle.
Alessign

Comment: Removing the original question with an update doesn't help anyone else who is reading your question, experiencing the same problem. Instead let the question be and accept the correct answer to help other people know _both_ the problem and the answer

Comment: What You done MR. Alessign ?   IS this post helpe any one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the error may be in the loop you use to shuffle the first array.
You don't post that part of your code...is it something like this?

```
for (int i=0; i<[indexes count]; i++){
// (...)
        [indexes removeObjectAtIndex:index]; 
// (...)
}
```

this may be better:

```
int arrayCount = [indexes count];
for (int i=0; i<arrayCount; i++){
// (...)
        [indexes removeObjectAtIndex:index]; 
// (...)
}
```

this complete code works well, with no errors or crashes:

```
int length = 10; 
NSMutableArray* indexes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:length];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) [indexes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
NSMutableArray*shuffle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:length];


int arrayCount = [indexes count];
for (int i=0; i<arrayCount; i++){

    int index = arc4random()%[indexes count];
    NSLog(@"___index: %i", index);
    NSLog(@"indexes: %@ ", indexes);

    [shuffle addObject:[indexes objectAtIndex:index]];
    [indexes removeObjectAtIndex:index]; 
    NSLog(@"shuffle: %@ ", shuffle);
}


for (int i=0; i<[shuffle count]; i++){
    int questionNumber = [[shuffle objectAtIndex:i] intValue] + 1; 
    NSLog(@"questionNumber: %i ", questionNumber);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! The problem with the code above is, if the method is in curly brackets, it will generate the outputs all together at once and when the second loop will come, it repeats the last one only and multiply arrays also, because the loops goes from top of the code to the bottom, so it creates infinite arrays.

Comment: I was trying to implement 'if' statement, but no effect at all `if (questionNumber == 10 && [shuffle count] < 10) {
        restartGame = NO;
       } `

Comment: well, of course, it was just a sample, i don't know the logic of your game outside of your question... you should implement the code depending on your needs

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but there is limitation 500 characters in comment and I can't to find the way to Reply long, just comment... ;-(

Comment: LOL... well, usually you can "Edit" your old question and add  text at the end (marking it clearly where the new edit lines starts), then comment here just to advice

Answer (score -1):

I see, anyway, Got it! I implemented one 'if' statement which will terminate it!
`if ([indexes count] == 0)

    {endProcess = YES}`

Comment: What you did, it have no use.